# Be very careful committing from the client! In fact, don’t do it

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrj, solrcloud

I created solr cloud cluster with 3 replicas and shards and configured with external zookeeper. Its working fine. After period of time I notice that when I restarted node it takes long time to start up.

I observe that in version in zookeeper on each node has huge amount of data in version-2 folder.After few days I noticed that nodes are down .recovery fail in many cases.

In my application I need live updates in cloud.so when user updates his profile I rewrite document to solr with `commit()` .

Is their something missing or live updates are not right option because thousands of peoples are updating their profiles same time?

Comment: You can either use explicit commit() (from a client), or use the auto commit feature (commitWithin). If you're making many small updates within a short time frame, doing explicit commits is probably not necessary. How many updates/sec are we talking about?

Comment: can't say each user is updating his own document .So one user one document will get updated just like I am updating in DB.thousands of users may be on line same time .

Comment: The Solr log files will tell you how many update requests are being performed; grep the logs and divide by the time :-)

Comment: request per second= 700